# MySQLdb failed to list all tables

Tags: python

I am utilising MySQLdb to query my MySQL db from my code, however, when I run `SHOW TABLES` it only lists 1 of the 2 tables within my database.

I am returned

```
('connections',)
```

When I am expecting

```
('connections','logs')
```

I am simplyin using `self.cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")` to get the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as 'sods law' would have it, as soon as I ask for help I figure it out myself. Kind of a stupid mistake on my behalf, it required more context to understand.

```
   for x in self.cursor:
        print(x)
        t = str(x).split("'")[1]
        z = str(x).split("'")[3]
        print(t, "\n", z)
        if t == constants.CONNECTIONS_TABLE:
            if z == constants.LOG_TABLE:
                break
            else:
                self.create_logs_table()
                break
        else:
            self.create_connections_table()
            break
```

My method was to check if the table existed and if not, create it. Well, I deided to use a for loop to go through the result of `self.cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")`. Well, this would make x only the first result of `SHOW TABLES`, so when I printed x out from inside the loop I would only see connections returned.

I have now re-written this method to be less stupid.